# Get form handle from point using pinvoke ignoring calling application

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I'm trying to rebuild the "Window Snip" functionality from the Microsoft "Snipping Tool"

I know how to get the boundaries of a window by first getting the window handle with p/invoke from the cursors point and after that getting the windows RECT also with a p/invoke method.

The problem I'm facing is that when I'm trying to implement an overlay like the snipping tool does I'm always getting my own applications handle.

I think the problem lies in the way I’m trying to implement that overlay. At the moment I am instancing a new form with the boundaries of the screen, Background is White with 50% opacity. I have a TransparencyKey with the color Fuchsia. My goal is that my overlay is completely transparent for the window where the mouse cursor is. (Like Snipping Tool does) For that I planning to draw a rectangle in Fuchsia with the boundaries of the underlying window to my overlay form (effectively making that spot transparent).

Is there a way to ignore my own window in the p/invoke method? Or is my idea to use a form for the overlay the wrong way to go and there is a simpler way to achieve the wanted behavior?

Comment: If you have a better topic don’t hesitate to give me a hint ;)

Comment: Thank you for the downvote unknown person, but knowing why you downvoted me will maybe help me to be more precise in future.

Comment: I changed your *C* tag to *C#* cause you are talking about *p/invoke*.

Comment: Don't you just need to capture what's on the Desktop in the area selected by your Application? Why do you care about a Window handle? Which Window? You might have more than a Window in a specific area. Try using just `graphics.CopyFromScreen(ScreenshotArea.Location, Point.Empty, ScreenshotArea.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);` The seletcted area is the one defined by the rectangle designed with a mouse pointer on your Window semi-transparent ClientArea..